# ionic `<ion-img>` doesn't work with domSanitizer, fails with "SafeValue must use [property]=binding"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4, capacitor

see example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-angular-tabs-6um4j8

I have the following url (from the local filesystem)

```js
url = 'capacitor://localhost/_capacitor_file_/Users/user/Library/.../Library/Caches/img/C409D956-DE09-406D-A7EF-3207DF705B64-L0-001~100x100.JPG';
safeUrl = domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
```

and I have this in the template file:

```html
<ion-virtual-scroll>
    <img [src]="safeUrl">
    <ion-img [src]="safeUrl"></ion-img>
</ion-virtual-scroll>
```

`safeUrl` displays correctly using the HTML IMG tag, but the same url in `<ion-img>` gives the following error:

```
"capacitor://localhost/SafeValue must use [property]=binding: capacitor://localhost/_capacitor_file_/Users/user/Library/.../Library/Caches/img/C409D956-DE09-406D-A7EF-3207DF705B64-L0-001~100x100.JPG (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't need to sanitize the url, instead try injecting the webview and using that to convertFileSrc

```ts
import { WebView } from '@ionic-native/ionic-webview/ngx';


...

constructor(private webview: WebView) {}

...

const localSrc = this.webView.convertFileSrc(url);
this.safeUrl = localSrc;
```